# Swift iOS SceneKit How do you secure encode an SCNMatrix4 with NSSecureCoding?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, nssecurecoding

I'm trying to secure encode a *SceneKit* `SCNMatrix4` so it conforms to `NSSecureCoding` with something akin to the following:

```
if let transform = aDecoder.decodeObject(of: SCNMatrix4.self, forKey: DATA_KEY_TRANSFORM) {
    self.transform = transform            
}
```

But this throws-up the compile error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'SCNMatrix4.Type' to expected argument
>   type '[AnyClass]?' (aka 'Optional>')

Obviously `SCNMatrix4` is not an object & is the reason why this doesn't work, but surely I don't need to go through every single one of the 16 `Float`s in the `SCNMatrix4` and encode each with:

```
aDecoder.decodeFloat(forKey: "someKey")
```

Surely not?

What is the correct way to secure encode this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggested one way as following, as same as in swiftShot examples:

`SCNMatrix4 = SCNMatrix.init(float4x4)`

`float4x4 <= self.column[0] = float4`

```
self.column[1] = float4
self.column[2] = float4
self.column[3] =  float4
```

`float4 <= with_4_Float.`

Answer (score 1):

Coding will require you to wrap the matrix into a `NSValue` first, and then unwrap it. See [`init(scnMatrix4:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsvalue/1409680-valuewithscnmatrix4) and [`scnMatrix4Value`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsvalue/1409684-scnmatrix4value).